# React: can't access the property of an array stored in state inside render function

Tags: reactjs

The response from an API call saved to state, when logged in console works.

```
.then(response => {
        this.setState({
            transactions: response,
        })
        if(this.state.transactions.meta.total > 0){
            console.log(this.state.transactions.data[0].id)
        }


    })
```

But when called inside the render function

```
this.state.transactions.meta.total > 0
?
<tbody>
  {
    this.state.transactions.data.map((transactions) => 
    <tr key={transactions.id}>
      <td>{transactions.status}</td>
      <td>{`${transactions.currency} ${transactions.amount / 100} from ${transactions.customer.email}`}</td>
      <td>{transactions.paid_at}</td>
    </tr>
    )
  }
</tbody>
:
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colSpan="3">There are no transactions at the moment</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

It doesn't work. What could I be getting wrong?

Comment: You need to wait for the async call to finish.

Comment: Please, how can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a loading State:

```
state = {
 loading: true
}
```

When the async call finishes set your loading to false:

```
.then(response => {
        this.setState({
            transactions: response,
            loading: false
        })
        if(this.state.transactions.meta.total > 0){
            console.log(this.state.transactions.data[0].id)
        }


    })
```

In render only try to render if loading is false:

```
!this.state.loading
?
<tbody>
  {
    this.state.transactions.data.map((transactions) => 
    <tr key={transactions.id}>
      <td>{transactions.status}</td>
      <td>{`${transactions.currency} ${transactions.amount / 100} from ${transactions.customer.email}`}</td>
      <td>{transactions.paid_at}</td>
    </tr>
    )
  }
</tbody>
:
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colSpan="3">Loading..</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```